# Preload animated gifs before anything else

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, gif, preload

Is there any way to preload an animated gif? I know there's a few questions kicking around about this but I've no luck with them. I have a simple overlay on my site, which has an animated gif as a background. When the site has loaded, it fades out.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#overlay-preload').delay(1000).fadeOut('fast');
});
```

The difficulty is, that on a mobile specifically, as the site is loading the animated gif is too and you get a really staggered loading of the gif. I've tried some preloading scripts but haven't had any luck. I wasn't sure if I was missing something? The gif is 4kb so it's not massive and you can view it here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eArlE.gif so on mobile you get this staggered fill effect.

Any thoughts or advice?

Comment: Do it the same way you'd preload any other image.

Comment: `I've tried some preloading scripts ` ..please show what you tried. We can't help otherwise

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to postpone the loading of your entire page into a callback when the gif was loaded, otherwise you'll always get stuttering in the animation:

**JavaScript**

```
loading_gif = new Image();
loading_gif.src = 'path/to/loader.gif';

loading_gif.onload = function () {
    // start loading your page (or loading animation)
};
```

This, however, greatly adds to the loading time, and *that's bad*. Why not use a [CSS animation](http://jsfiddle.net/m3by862h/1/) instead?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, in a way, the loader needs to be that logo.

Comment: @braw While not a trivial task, it should be entirely possible to create that logo and animate it with CSS.